# Generator and Encoder network model

Tags: python, ai, neural-network

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.07047v1.pdf

I don't have a lot of experience in building a network model. I would like to build the `Encoder` and `Generator` network model from the above article.

Here is my attempt :

```
import torch.nn as nn

class ResnetBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, norm_layer, activation=nn.ReLU(False), kernel_size=3):
        super().__init__()

        pw = (kernel_size - 1) // 2
        self.conv_block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ReflectionPad2d(pw),
            norm_layer(nn.Conv2d(dim, dim, kernel_size=kernel_size)),
            activation,
            nn.ReflectionPad2d(pw),
            norm_layer(nn.Conv2d(dim, dim, kernel_size=kernel_size)),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.conv_block(x)
        out = x + y
        return out

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    """
    Network used for the VAE (Encoder) as well as in the GAN (i.e. Discriminator).
    In other words, it is the same architecture as the image discriminator.
    
    Attributes:
        num_features (int) : 
    """
    
    def __init__(self, num_features):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_features, 256, knernel_size=7, stride=1)
            nn.Conv2d(256, 128, knernel_size=4, stride=2)
            nn.Conv2d(128, 64, knernel_size=4, stride=2)
        )
        
        self.resnet_block = ResnetBlock(64, kernel_size=3)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        
        out = self.encoder(x)
        out = self.resnet_block(out)
        
        return out

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features):
        super().__init__()

        self.resnet_block = ResnetBlock(64, kernel_size=3)

        self.generator = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, knernel_size=4, stride=2)
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, knernel_size=4, stride=2)
            nn.Conv2d(256, num_features, knernel_size=7, stride=1)
        )
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.resnet_block(x)
        out = self.generator(x)
        return out
```

I am not sure the model Encoder and Generator are properly well coded according to

[image]

Comment: Hey Alex, if you're not sure your code works, sadly it means it's not a good fit for this site. The goal of a code review is to review code that works, otherwise it's not so much reviewing as writing the code for you. You could start by comparing the table in the article to the one generated by ` model.summary()` , it might help!

Comment: @IEatBagels I am not saying the code doesn't work. I am saying I need help reviewing the code in itself. I am not sure if the `Encoder` and `Generator` are well defined corresponding the detailed structure network. This is only where I need help.

Comment: I understand your point. The thing is, you do not know if it works as expected (the expected architecture being the paper's one). In this case, it's not so much a code review as to help you figure out if your code does what it's supposed to do, which is off-topic. I think this just isn't the right fit for CodeReview.

Comment: Have you run the code and does it work as expected? If you have run the code can you please supply the test cases? One of the ways we could help is to point out test cases that you haven't tried.